# Convert this Sqlite query to SQL Server returning values on the matching aggregate row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

This query uses an Sqlite-specific feature to return the information on the row with the minimum timestamp per group (since 3.7.11). However, SQL Server says that all the columns returned in a query with a group-by clause must have some kind of aggregate.

How do I convert this query to SQL Server 2012?

```
SELECT 
    Id, MIN(TimestampTicks), TelemetryId, Value 
FROM 
    Events 
WHERE 
    TelemetryId in (1690, 1691, 1692, 1700) 
GROUP BY 
    TelemetryId
```

Comment: Dont know about Sqlite, but in sql server if you have used an aggregate function , all the other column that are not contained in any aggregate function must come in group by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SQL Server you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function to get the same behavior; the row for each telemetryid which has the lowest timestampticks value will have row number 1 in each group;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, timestampticks, telemetryid, value, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY telemetryid
                        ORDER BY timestampticks) rn
  FROM Events WHERE telemetryid in (1690, 1691, 1692, 1700) 
)
SELECT id, timestampticks, telemetryid, value FROM cte WHERE rn=1;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ad9a/1).

Comment: The non-aggregate columns returned with a `GROUP BY` in Sqlite (>= v3.7.11) are not arbitrary values. They are the values from the row matching the aggregate.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson really cant see any difference in the sql fiddle with both queries. could you please point out ??

Comment: @Brannon Updated with the result you seem to want, can't repeat your desired behavior in SQLite on SQLfiddle though.

Comment: To see my behavior, change your fiddle example to have different values (in the Value column) on each row. Then switch to sql.js for the engine.

Comment: @Brannon Ok, then I understood the result you were looking for correctly with this new query.

Comment: Yes, the new query definitely works. I'm slightly concerned about performance on it. Running some tests on my real data shows that the inner query returns about 100k rows in a table of 5 million. I'm seeing total query time reported at 240ms. Is there some way to narrow the rows returned in that inner query?

Comment: Since value is not in the index, I was able to get a 10x speedup by joining in value on the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, MIN(TimestampTicks), TelemetryId, Value 
FROM  Events 
WHERE TelemetryId in (1690, 1691, 1692, 1700) 
GROUP BY Id, TelemetryId, Value
```

Dont know about Sqlite, but in sql server if you have used an aggregate function in SELECT, all the other column that are not contained in any aggregate function must come in group by clause, Sql Server needs to know how to aggregate values in the column.

Comment: Grouping by Id causes more than four rows to be returned. That's definitely not right.

Comment: @Brannon see the sql fiddle exmaple in Joachim Isaksson's answer both queries return exactly the same results.

Comment: please explain how you got to the answer instead of just giving it